# unable to get managed connections if you are leaking connections

Tags: java, managed, connection

I have quite a few of methods that run some inserts and updates. One example is as follows:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public void insertStuff( String crap1, String crap2 ) throws SQLException {
   Connection conn = null;
   PreparedStatement ps1 = null;
   try
   {
      String sqlStr = " INSERT INTO ... "
                    + " VALUES (? , ? )" ;

      conn = JNDIUtil.getConnection();
      ps1 = conn.prepareStatement(sqlStr);
      ps1.setString(1, crap1);
      ps1.setString(2, crap2);
      ps1.executeUpdate();

   } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
   } finally {
      DbUtils.close(ps1);
      DbUtils.close(conn);
   }
}
```

My JNDIUtil is :

```
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public final class JNDIUtil {

    private static final String JDBC_DB_URL = "blah";

    public static Connection getConnection() {
        Connection conn = null;

        try {
            Context ctx = (Context) new InitialContext();
            DataSource ds = (DataSource)ctx.lookup(JDBC_DB_URL);
            conn = ds.getConnection();
        } catch (final SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (final NamingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return conn;
    }
}
```

Now, this is a jboss eap 6.4 server. I limited the max pool size in order to replicate the same error that happens in production  :

```
<max-pool-size>10</max-pool-size>
```

When I run a load test with JMeter using 20 threads firing at the same time, I get the following error :

I get the following error :

```
16:05:20,018 ERROR [stderr] (http-/127.0.0.1:8085-19) java.sql.SQLException: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000453: Unable to get managed connection for blah
```

Each method has a close prepared statement, close result set, and close connection in the reverse order they are created. By the way, DBUtils.close() is from Apache Commons DBUtils.  When I look at JBoss Management Console, I see that available connections drop to 0.

Why are these connections not being closed when each method is being executed?

Comment: you close `ps1` but you create `ps = conn.prepareStatement(sqlStr);`? Are you sure your example is correct ? And if you are in JDK7++, you should use try-with-resources (eg: `try (Connection conn = ...) {}`), this would handle the close for you in a safe manner.

Comment: @NoDataFound, it is ps1 indeed. I am using 8.